# how to integrate Magento eCommerce with Openbravo?

Tags: magento2, openbravo

I have Openbravo Erp and I want to integrate with Magento2 eCommerce 
How to sync ORDERS and Inventory data to Openbravo ERP using API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openbravo does have an ***Openbravo Magento Connector*** Module for connecting Openbravo ERP and Magento eCommerce systems under commercial licensing. With the help of this module, one can synchronize the customer data, product information and sales orders using a scheduler job.

Please go through the [***Openbravo Magento Connector***](http://centralrepository.openbravo.com/openbravo/org.openbravo.forge.ui/ForgeProjectDetail/Openbravo%20Magento%20Connector) project page for downloading the related modules.

Please check the project [***wiki***](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects/SigmaInfoSolutions-OpenbravoMagentoConnector) page for technical specifications and how-tos.

In case, if you are using Openbravo 2.50, please find the installation guide ***[here](http://forge.openbravo.com/plugins/mwiki/images/f/f7/ERP-Magento_Installation_Guide_2.0.pdf)***.